# create executable .exe file from javafx project with JRE

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, exe, launch4j

I have a `JavaFX` project and I'm trying to get an executable `exe` file from it. I use `launch4j` and `Inno` setup wizard technologies for it. My `exe` file works only in computers which have java in them, but doesn't work in computers that don't have java installed.

I want to create `exe` file so it includes `JRE`, so it works in all computers. 
I am showing how I do it in [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12HGiwMU_3Nmsq1qWGn4s8pkhPdUxXALj) video

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hello friend this should help you : 
https://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse

Comment: If a JRE is included, it will not work on all computers because JavaFX has os-dependant libraries. If you can change to Java 9 or higher you can use JLink to create an exe.

Answer (score 0):

In java8 you can use "Javapackager". You don't need launch4j or innosetup.

Additionnaly From version java 13 (available in early-access) there is a tool named "jPackage" with which you can create an msi, exe, deb or rpm depending on your OS and options. But there will be a little difficulty, because javaFX is no more packaged in the jdk, and you need a module declaration to make work the tools chain (jlink then jpackage)
It's a lot of work to upgrade your project from 8 to 13, but it could be usefull for later consultation of your question:
see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343